# Safari 11.0 is blocking some of our scripts

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, safari

Here is a quick video describing the issue - https://screencast.com/t/zTnbBoWYmY
Since the new Safari 11 we have an issue where our content isn't loading properly.

We are getting messages such as

> SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): Blocked a frame with origin `"https://staticxx.facebook.com"` from accessing a frame with origin `"https://bookretreats.com"`. The frame requesting access set `"document.domain"` to `"facebook.com"`, but the frame being accessed did not. Both must set `"document.domain"` to the same value to allow access.

and

> SecurityError (DOM Exception 18): Blocked a frame with origin `"https://vars.hotjar.com"` from accessing a frame with origin `"https://bookretreats.com"`. Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

I'm thinking this is causing a block of some elements, but I'm not sure, how to tackle this.

Comment: the URL in the example is - https://bookretreats.com/s/yoga-retreats

Comment: Sorry but this question is considered off-topic because the error encountered is a JavaScript (DOM) issue. Stack Overflow is more appropriate for this issue but you will need to narrow down the JavaScript code that is causing the issue before reposting their. Please visit their help centre for further advice, also worth searching for [Dom Exception 18](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=DOM+Exception+18) as it looks to be asked and answered many times on SO.